# Python FIN Scan

Tags: python-3.x, networking

I'm trying to build a FIN scan with python3.5 using scapy. I send a FIN packet and in case the port is opened the server should ignore my request, in case it is closed I should get a RST packet back. I'm getting nothing and I've already tried many hosts, plus using an xmas scan I have the same problem. Am I doing something wrong? Here's the code :

```
...
ip_p = IP(dst=host_ip)
tcp_p  = TCP(dport=(1,100),flags='F')
packets = ip_p/tcp_p
resp, non_resp = sr(packets,timeout=0.5)
for item in non_resp:
    print(item.sport)
for sent,recv in resp:
    if recv[1].flags == 4 : # 4 == RST packet
        print('[>]Port:',sent[1].dport,'closed, but !port service on!')
    if recv[1].flags != 4 :
        print('[!]Port:',sent[1].dport,'opened')
        print(recv[1].flags)
```